# I couldn't / wasn't able to drink coffee (come home late) when I was 10 years old

Tags: modal-verbs, could-modal

Please, help me to understand the usage of these modals better.

As I think, the most appropriate answer is

> **I wasn't able to drink coffee (come home late) when I was 10 years old.**

*because* these situations are not about physical abilities (as something wrong with swallowing liquid or with legs :), but about external circumstances e.g. parents' rules, drinking coffee restrictions.

What's your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

At 10 years of age, your issue is usually **permission** rather than ability.

Your parents/guardians are in charge of pretty much everything you do. You don't really have any say in things.

So, you really want to say

> I didn't have permission to drink coffee (come home late) when I was 10 years old.

but, wow, that's a bit formal, so you'd soften it to

> I wasn't **allowed** to drink coffee (come home late) when I was 10 years old.

& everybody knows you lacked the permission rather than the ability.

From comments:-

"Couldn't" would work, but it's more ambiguous…

> I couldn't drive when I was 16.

Permission or ability? I think 'allowed' removes any ambiguity.

Comment: In this instance, "couldn't" would still be appropriate to convey permission, though. See here (https://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-modals.php) that "can" indicates permission, possibility or ability. If I had to choose between "couldn't" and "wasn't able", I would say it would be "couldn't".

Comment: "I couldn't drive when I was 16" Permission or ability? I think 'allowed' removes any ambiguity.

Comment: Of course, yes. However, from the question posed by @Hüsna Kefelioğlu, it seemed like we had to choose from the options there? That said, I agree that "allowed" is far more clear.

Comment: I've added that to the answer, thanks for bringing it up - of course, there will be many times where ambiguity is considerably less.

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment, I meant to tag @NadinSh.

Comment: Thanks, but if you tell me that I can't use modals in such sentences I'm confused, bc I can see such examples as    ''Byron Vincent grew up on a rough housing estate were children weren't able to get a good education''. Obviously getting the education wasn't up to Byron, wasn't his physical/mental ability, but depended on circumstances. So, parents' rules are such circumstances, aren't they?

Comment: Your example above has no permission element at all, so the ambiguity isn't there. They were not able to get a good education because one simply wasn't available to them.

Comment: According the Collin's dictionary, "If you are able to do something, you have enough freedom, power, time, or money to do it". Freedom is what I was thinking at first, is there any chance that it's possible to use "be able to" in such a sentence?    https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-able-to